# Resource Owner Password Credentials token results in 401 on Azure Function App

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I would like to use the Resource Owner Password Credential Flow of Azure AD for my function app. The function app is up and running. Once I configure Azure AD authentication for the app, my requests get rejected with a `401 Unauthorized` but with no further details on the error.

I should also emphasize that I can obtain new tokens from the authentication endpoint for my tenant. It's just that these tokens get rejected when I try to call the function from `curl`. When I login with the browser and the same credentials, I can access the function.

**Clarification: Obtaining tokens via the API works but these tokens are then rejected by the function app's AAD authentification. Going through the browser, I obtain tokens that can log me into the function app.**

---

### What I did:

#### Create a function app

- Basic `GET` request, works with either no authorization or with authorization through the browser.

#### Create an app registration in Azure AD

- Implicit grant: Access + ID Token
- Supported account types: Single Tenant
- Allow public client flow: Yes
- In the manifest: `"oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,`
- Scopes: Custom `user_impersonation` scope for my API
- API: Here I added my function app with the `user_impersonation` scope

#### Configure the function app to authenticate user through AAD

- Management mode: Advanced
- Client ID: The client ID of the app registration above
- Allowed Token Audiences: The URL of my function

### Steps to reproduce:

#### Obtain a new `access_token`:

Issue a `POST` request to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token and the following parameters:

- `clientId`: The client ID of the app registration in Azure AD
- `scope`: `user.read openid profile offline_access https://<my-function>.azurewebsites.net/user_impersonation`
- `username`: The e-mail address of the user
- `password`: The password of the user
- `grant_type`: `password`

This returns the `access_token`. I'm not going to post it here, but I can share details on request.

#### Call the protected API

Issue a `GET` request to `https://<my-function>.azurewebsites.net/api/test` with the following header parameter:

- `Authorization`: `Bearer <access_token>`

---

Any help is greatly appreciated of course. It is important to note that users should not be able to login interactively anyway. I'm well aware of the pitfalls and shortcomings of the ROPC flow but this is the only way to solve this particular use case with Azure AD.

Here are some resouces I consulted before. I might have overlooked a critical point of course:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=app-reg-ga (Not using AAD B2C but is probably similar enough. However the steps mentioned here work.)

Comment: Is the account you are using has MFA enabled ? (Also, you will have to confirm whether MFA is disabled outside the org network )

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not the problem. I guess I wouldn‘t be able to aquire the token in the first place with MFA enabled.

Comment: You mentioned that you are able to get the tokens only when you authenticate through the browser. Browser passes device information, there could be configuration to by pass the MFA when device information is passed along. That is the reason I suspected it could be MFA.

Comment: Where as curl - doesn't pass along the device information and can be subjected to MFA.

Comment: A quick check would be to try to login in a in private / in cognito browser session - check whether you are able to login with out any MFA prompts.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I clarified what I meant in the first section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it. The solution was a lot of trial an error, maybe there is an easier way.

#### Azure AD App Registration

- Only select the access token, we don't need an ID token anyway.
- Set `"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2` in the manifest
- Use the suggested `api://...` Application ID

#### Function App

- Set both the Client ID and the Allowed Token Audience to the Application ID from the AAD App Registration, but without the leading `api://` scheme.

#### Obtaining the token

- Specify the scope as `api://.../user_impersonation`

After going through all of the steps above, I can successfully authenticate before being able to access my function app. The next challenge will be to read the authenticated user name from the request. But that might be the topic of another thread on SO.